# cmake undefined reference

Tags: cmake, undefined-reference

I am using cmake to build my project, but I am getting these errors.

```
Scanning dependencies of target las2vtk
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/las2vtk.dir/LAS2VTK.cxx.o
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/las2vtk.dir/PointSet.cxx.o
Linking CXX executable las2vtk
CMakeFiles/las2vtk.dir/LAS2VTK.cxx.o: In function `main':
LAS2VTK.cxx:(.text+0xf1): undefined reference to `PointSet<PointND<3, float> >::read_LAS(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, int)'
LAS2VTK.cxx:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `PointSet<PointND<3, float> >::write_VTK(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [las2vtk] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/las2vtk.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I am confused why those functions are undefined when they are written in PointSet.cxx. Below is my CMakeLists.txt file. Currently PointSet.h, PointSet.cxx, and LAS2VTK.cxx are all in the same folder, but I might change that.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

PROJECT(las2vtk)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")

set(SOURCES PointSet.cxx)

set(LASLIBS_INCLUDE "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/lastools/laslib/inc")
set(LASLIBS_LIB "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/lastools/laslib/lib")

include_directories(${LASLIBS_INCLUDE})
link_directories(${LASLIBS_LIB})
set(LASLIBS las)

add_executable(las2vtk LAS2VTK.cxx ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(las2vtk ${LASLIBS})

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})

if(VTK_LIBRARIES)
  target_link_libraries(las2vtk ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
else()
  target_link_libraries(las2vtk vtkHybrid )
endif()
```

It compiled just fine when I had my function definitions within my PointSet.h file and had no PointSet.cxx file but I wanted to clean up the code base.

Comment: It looks like you are defining a template. In that case, the implementation has to be in the header file, as the compiler must be able to see both the template definition, and the definition of the types used to instantiate it.